# Spring Roo Detail Object

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-roo

I'm using Spring roo v2.0. I created a simple app with two entities: Library and Book. A Library can have more books so I created a relashionship one-to-many. 
I used the following command to create the project:

```
project setup --topLevelPackage com.library 
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY 
entity jpa --class ~.Library 
field string --fieldName identifier  --notNull
entity jpa --class ~.Book  
field string --fieldName identifier  --notNull
focus --class ~.Library
field set --fieldName book --type ~.Book --mappedBy library --notNull false --cardinality ONE_TO_MANY
repository jpa --all --package ~.repository
service --all --apiPackage ~.service.api --implPackage ~.service.impl 
web mvc setup
web mvc view setup --type THYMELEAF
web mvc controller --all --responseType JSON
web mvc controller --all --responseType THYMELEAF
web mvc detail --all --responseType THYMELEAF
```

My problem..
When I edit/show a library detail I'd want to show its books as happens in the list librabry page after select one.

And then... in this form I'd want to have an Add button that create a book for that library, not a generic book.

How can I do it? Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should customize manually the `show.html` view related with the `Library` entity to include a table with that information.

To do that, you could include in the `model` of the method that serves the `show` page the complete list of books using a `findBooksByLibrary` method. Something like this:

```
@Override
@GetMapping(name = "show")
public ResponseEntity<Library> show(@ModelAttribute Library library, Model model) {
   model.addAttribute("books", getBookService().findByLibrary(library));
   return new ModelAndView("libraries/show");
}
```

After that, edit the `show.html` page including a `table` element that shows the previous related books:

```
<table data-th-each="item : ${books}">
 <tr>
   <td data-th-text="${item.identifier}"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

NOTE: Remember that you could use Datatables JQuery plugin to give extra features to the table above.

Hope it helps